# Real Time Multiple object detection from mulitple videos, while correcting image distortion

Tags: c++, opencv, video, camera, object-detection

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to detect multiple objects from multiple videos at the same time and I am also correcting the distortion in the videos so I can get an accurate reading for the bearing of the detections relative to the camera.

I'm working with OpenCV, in C++ using Visual Studio 2010

The code works but it is very slow, not real time.  I am hoping someone may have suggestions as how it may be sped up, if it can. I'm not much of a coder at present and learning about image processing and don't know many tricks.

What the code does in a general sense is:

-Opens a video file

-Applies distortion correction to each image frame (for bearings)

-Crops the image (improves detections, time stamps give false positives)

-Applies a Haar type cascade to the cropped image to detect objects

-Draws a bounding box around the detections

-Displays the images

-It calculates the angle of the detections of the objects and prints to terminal

-It also draws an image like a radar, and displays the angle relative to the camera of each detection in each frame, the idea is to have it as a single source giving the detections from each camera on a single source mapping out the surrounding area.

I've included the main code that runs the video and detections for a single video, this is still pretty slow and takes approx. 18 seconds for each second of video.  And when I have 4 videos attempting to run it's about 3 times longer.

Video dimensions are 704x576.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated, or even just knowing that it can only be sped up with purpose designed hardware.

Cheers,
Dave

```
int main(){

/////////////////////////////
//**Distortion Correction**//
/////////////////////////////

std::cout<< endl << "Reading:" << endl;
//stores a file
FileStorage fs;
//reads and stores the xml file with the camera calibration
fs.open("cal2.xml", FileStorage::READ);

if (fs.isOpened()) 
{
    cout<<"File is opened\n";

}


//Mat objects to store the camera matrix and distortion coefficients
Mat CamMat, DistCoeff;

FileNode n = fs.root();

//takes the parameters from the xml file and stores them in the Mat objects
fs["Camera_Matrix"] >> CamMat;
fs["Distortion_Coefficients"] >> DistCoeff;


/////////////////////
//**Video Display**//
/////////////////////

//Mat objects to store the images
Mat Original, Vid1, Vid1Crop;

//Cropping Image to exclude time/camera stamps to improve detections
Rect roi(0, 35, 704, 490);

//for reading video or webcam
VideoCapture cap;
//for opening video file, give the location and name of the file seperating folders with "\\" instead of with a single "\"
cap.open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Run_01_005 two containers\\Video\\ch04_20140219124355.mp4");


//Windows for the images
namedWindow("New", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
namedWindow("Display", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);

///////////////////////
//**Detection Setup**//
///////////////////////

// Cascade Classifier object
CascadeClassifier boat_cascade;

//loads the xml file for the classifier, put the address and name of the xml file in the brackets
boat_cascade.load( "boatcascadeAttp3.xml" );

/////////////////////////////////////
//**Single Source Display Image**////
/////////////////////////////////////
Mat Output; 

//loop to continually capture/update images
    while (1){

    Output = Display();


        cap>>Original;

        //applies the distortion correction to input image and outputs to New image
        undistort(Original, Vid1, CamMat, DistCoeff, noArray());

        //Image excluding the time/camera stamps in video which caused a lot of false positives
        Vid1Crop = Vid1(roi);
        //Set.NewCrop(New, roi);

        // Detect boats
        std::vector<Rect> boats;
        //Parameters may need some further adjustment, currently seems to work well
        //Detection performed on Region of Interest that excludes the time stamp which caused a number of False Positives
        boat_cascade.detectMultiScale( Vid1Crop, boats, 1.1, 15, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(25, 25), Size(75,75) );

        // Draw circles on the detected boats
        for( int i = 0; i < boats.size(); i++ )
        {

            //Draws a box around the detected object
            rectangle( Vid1Crop, Point(boats[i].x, boats[i].y), Point(boats[i].x+boats[i].width, boats[i].y+boats[i].height), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 2, 8);

            //finds the position of the detection along the X axis
            int centreX = boats[i].x + boats[i].width*0.5;
            int fromCent = Vid1Crop.cols - centreX;

            float angle;

            //calls Angle function
            angle = Angle(centreX, fromCent, Vid1Crop);

            //calls DisplayPoints function
            Point XYpoints = DisplayPoints(angle);

            //prints out the result, angle for cam ranges
            cout << angle;
            cout << " degrees" << endl;
            //Draws red circles on the single source display corresponding to the detections
            circle( Output, XYpoints, 5.0, Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ), 4, 8 );
}

        //shows the New output image after correction
        imshow("New", Vid1);
        imshow("Display", Output);

        //delay for 1ms between frames  -  Note 25 fps in video
        waitKey(1);

}


fs.release();
return (0);
```

}

Comment: Profiling is a way to find out what part of your code is heavy on time. But since you mentioned you're new to coding, this is going to be difficult.

Comment: Thank you, I was completely unaware of "profiling," looks interesting.  I'll have a look into it.

Comment: Also I realised I called some #include things that I didn't need, once I removed them the speed improved, still not what I need but better